# set custom font for alert messages for both android and ios using xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using xamarin forms for my project. I need to set custom font family(Montserrat-Medium.ttf) for the following alert messages for both android and iOS.

```
var ans = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("", "Are you want to leave the application?", "Yes", "No");
```

Anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in shared Xamarin project, but you can simply create a custom alert, and do what ever you want with it, like this:

[image]

### Add your font to the solution

1. Add the font somewhere in shared project and then right click on it and choose **Properties**.
2. In Properties, choose **Embedded resource** as a **Build Action**.
3. Add this line

```
[assembly: ExportFont("Montserrat-Medium.ttf", Alias = "MyMontserrat")]
```

to the `AssemblyInfo.cs`

### Create custom popup view like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="MyApp.MainPage">
    <AbsoluteLayout Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Button Text="Display Alert!"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Clicked="OnButtonClicked" />
    </StackLayout>

<!--Here's the custom popupView-->
        <ContentView x:Name="popupView" BackgroundColor="#C0808080" Padding="10, 0" IsVisible="false" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HeightRequest="150" WidthRequest="200" BackgroundColor="White">
                    <Label x:Name="myLabel" FontSize="16" FontFamily="MyMontserrat" Text="Are you want to leave the application?" />
                    <Button Text="Yes" FontSize="16" FontFamily="MyMontserrat" BackgroundColor="White" TextTransform="None" Clicked="Yes_Clicked" />
                    <Button Text="No" FontSize="16" FontFamily="MyMontserrat" BackgroundColor="White" TextTransform="None" Clicked="No_Clicked" />
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentView>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

### Use your popup in .cs

```
        void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            //This will show the pop up
            popupView.IsVisible = true;
        }

        private void Yes_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            popupView.IsVisible = false;
            //Your stuff here
        }

        private void No_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            popupView.IsVisible = false;
            //Your stuff here
        }
```

Comment: @Arun Does this answer your question? Please let me know by [accepting/upvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it does. Otherwise, please leave the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to call the native dialog,and define the font in the native dialog.

Here is a simple sample for Android (ios is similar to this,you could refer to [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/109745/xamarin-forms-displayalert-with-italic-font-attribute)):

define a interface in your forms project:

```
public interface ICustomAlert
{
  void Show(string message);

}
```

then in your Android project:

```
public class CustomAlert : ICustomAlert
{

  public void Show(string message)
  {
        AndroidX.AppCompat.App.AlertDialog.Builder alertdialogbuilder = new AndroidX.AppCompat.App.AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.Instance);
        alertdialogbuilder.SetMessage(message);
        alertdialogbuilder.SetPositiveButton("Yes",OkEvent);
        alertdialogbuilder.SetNeutralButton("No", NoEvent);
        AndroidX.AppCompat.App.AlertDialog alertdialog = alertdialogbuilder.Create();
        alertdialog.Show();
        TextView textView = alertdialog.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Message);
        textView.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Red);
        
        Typeface face = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(MainActivity.Instance.Assets, "fonts/Montserrat-Medium.tff");
        textView.SetTypeface(face, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
  }

    private void NoEvent(object sender, DialogClickEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void OkEvent(object sender, DialogClickEventArgs e)
    {
    }

}
```

then you could call like

```
DependencyService.Get<ICustomAlert>().Show("your message");
```